# Is there a built-in method to get a URL minus the query string?

Tags: go

Is there a built-in method to get the portion of a URL minus the query string? Like `http://example.com/` from `http://example.com/?search=test`?

It's trivial to assemble from the fields of the URL struct (or even by splitting on the question mark char) so I'm not looking for sample code. This is just a simple question to see if it's there in the source/docs and I'm missing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who are searching for this information, the correct answer is no, there isn't a built-in method for this, and it can be handled as I described in my question, or as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no convenience function for your exact use case.

but, you can use the `net/url` package to create one:

http://play.golang.org/p/Kk3EPBXMsm

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    result, err := url.Parse("http://example.com/?search=test?")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Invalid url", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result.Scheme+"://"+result.Host+result.Path)
    // or
    result.RawQuery = ""

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, both look good: the first method is assembling it from the fields of the URL struct as mentioned, and I hadn't considered the second so that's a nice option. I was just wondering if there's a convenience method built into the url package or elsewhere in the standard library that I was missing. (I upvoted you anyway.)

Comment: Hi @SexxLuthor, no; there's no convenience function for your exact use case.

Comment: Thanks @tomwilde, your answer is actually the correct one (though the sample code here can help others who stumble onto this question ;).